# Prove that $a^{4/a} + b^{4/b} + c^{4/c} \ge 3$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Let $a, b, c > 0$ with $a + b + c = 3$. Prove that
> $$a^{4/a} + b^{4/b} + c^{4/c} \ge 3.$$

This question was [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4493800) recently, closed and then deleted, due to missing of contexts etc.

By https://approach0.xyz/, the problem was [proposed](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1281308p6741201) by Grotex@AoPS.

My strategy is to split into many cases.

WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c$.

If $a \ge 8/5$, true.

If $a \le 10/7$, let
$f(x) = x^{4/x} - 1  - 4(x - 1)$.
We have $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in (0, 10/7)$.

If $10/7 < a < 8/5$ and $b \ge 4/5$, true.

(I stopped here since this approach is ugly. Actually, the proof of $x^{4/x} - 1  - 4(x - 1) \ge 0$ for all $x\in (0, 10/7)$ is complicated.)

I hope to see nice proofs.

Comment: I've found that $f(x) = x^{1/x}$ has its *maximum* value at $x = e$, but this doesn't help as much for a *lower* bound.

Comment: Maybe Lagrange multiplier can find the minimum of that smooth function.

Comment: @Mason I think so. Also, I prefer non-LM approaches. LM is something like "Break a butterfly on the wheel".

Comment: Can you see the deleted post? It seems that a user wrote an answer using the Bernoulli inequality. While I haven't verified it, it goes as follows : write $a=x+1,b=y+1,c=z+1$, and  use $(x+1)^{\frac 4{x+1}} \geq 1+\frac{4x}{x+1}$ (and likewise for the others) using Bernoulli's inequality, and sum up to finish. I think there is something wrong after the summing up, personally, but I'll leave this up to indicate that Bernoulli might be a way out.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Yes, I can see that answer. The author deleted it (I think there is something wrong).

Comment: @RiverLi Looking back, there probably is. There is an assertion that $\frac{4x}{x+1} + \frac{4y}{y+1} + \frac{4z}{z+1} \geq 0$, which reduces to $\frac{x}{x+1}+\frac{y}{y+1} + \frac{z}{z+1} \geq 0$ whenever $x+y+z=0$. That, I'm not sure it's true and would cause the proof to collapse. Perhaps one can go one level "deeper" in Bernoulli's inequality, maybe.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I believe Bernoulli's inequality plays some role here.

Comment: grotex, Crazy_littleboy, fjw.., @HN_NH proposed so many hard problems.

Comment: @ĐặngHảiĐăng Yes, some of those problems are still open in some sense.

Comment: Trivially, if $a = b = c = 1$, then $f(a) + f(b) + f(c) = 3$.  So the challenge is to prove that that is the *minimum* sum on the given domain plane.

Comment: You write: "Actually, the proof of $x^{4/x} - 1  - 4(x - 1) \ge 0$ for all $x\in (0, 10/7)$ is complicated." It can be done with calculus, see my answer below for details.

Comment: @Andreas I think that my proof and your proof for $x^{4/x} \ge 4x - 3$ on some interval $(0, c)$ using calculus are both complicated. In contrast, using Bernoulli, it is one line: $$x^{4/x} = (x^{\frac{4}{3x}})^3
\ge \Big(1 + (x - 1)\cdot \frac{4}{3x}\Big)^3
= 4x - 3 + \frac{4(52x - 27x^2 - 16)(x - 1)^2}{27x^3} \ge 4x - 3.$$

Comment: Bernoulli, in the form which you use, only holds for $\frac{4}{3x} \ge 1$, i.e. $x \le \frac{4}{3}$, hence it does only prove the desired result for $1 \le x \le  \frac{4}{3} \sim 1.333$. But we want it for  $1 \le x \le  \frac{10}{7} \sim 1.429$, so this is not a one-liner.

Comment: @Andreas I split into $(0, 4/3)$ and $(4/3, c)$ which are both proved by Bernoulli. This is much simpler and elementary than taking derivative and second derivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before the actual proof, let's start with a discussion of $f(x) = x^{4/x}$ which is needed later.

We have
$ df(x) /dx = 4 x^{4/x - 2} (1 - \log(x))$ so $f(x)$ is rising for all $0 < x  < e$ which is all we need to consider below. Further,
$$ d^2f(x) /dx^2 = 4 x^{4/x - 4} (-3 x + 4 \log^2(x) + 2 (x - 4) \log(x) + 4)$$
To interpret this result for positive and negative ranges, consider $ h(x) =  -3 x + 4 \log^2(x) + 2 (x - 4) \log(x) + 4$. Clearly, $h(x) {{(x\to 0) } \atop{\longrightarrow}} \infty $. Further,
$$ h'(x) = (-x + 2 (x + 4) \log(x) - 8)/x
$$
which remains negative for at least $0 < x < 2$. So if we have a value where $d^2f(x) /dx^2$ changes sign in the range $0 < x < 2$, this will be the only sign change there. The sign change indeed occurs near $x= 1.125$.

We can now describe the behavior of $f(x) = x^{4/x}$ for $0 < x  < 2$. It is rising, it is convex for   $0 < x  < x_0 $ and concave for $ x_0 < x  < 2$ where $x_0≈1.125$ is the unique real solution of $h(x)=0$ on $(0,2)$.

Now consider $g(x) = -3 + 4x$. Note $g(x)$ touches $f(x) = x^{4/x}$ at $x=1$, since $g(1) =f(1) = 1$ and $g'(1) = f'(1) = 4$. Since $x^{4/x}$ is convex at $x=1$ and turns concave at $x \simeq 1.125$, we have an "S-shape" and hence,  there is at most one intersection $g(x) = f(x)$ in the range  $1.125 < x  < 2$. By inspection we   have that this occurs near $\bar{x} = 1.429$ . So $x^{4/x} \ge g(x)$ for $x < \bar{x} = 1.429$ and hence, for $a,b,c < \bar{x}$, $a^{4/a} + b^{4/b} + c^{4/c} \ge  -9 + 4(a+b+c) =3$.

As OP already noted, only $1.52 > a \ge b \ge c$ must then be considered (since $1.52^{4/1.52} > 3$) . Now if $1.52 > a > \bar{x} = 1.429$, then $a^{4/a} \ge \bar{x}^{4/\bar{x}} \simeq 2.71$ and $b +c \ge 3 - 1.52 = 1.48$. Hence it remains to be shown that for  $b +c = 1.48$, that $b^{4/b} + c^{4/c} \ge 3 - 2.71 = 0.29$. This can be established by direct calculation, since indeed $b^{4/b} + (1.48-b)^{4/(1.48-b)} > 0.29$ for all $0 \le b \le 1.48$. $\qquad \Box$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For a complete proof, I think the details should be given. For example, it might be difficult (or complicated) to prove that $x^{4/x} \ge 1 + 4(x-1)$ on $(0, 1.429)$. Also, even the convexity of $x^{4/x}$ is not easy.

Comment: Dear River Li, I augmented by starting with a discussion of $f(x) = x^{4/x}$.

Comment: Thanks. The following statement is not accurate: "it is convex for   $0 < x  < 1.125$ and concave for $1.125 < x  < 2$." $1.125$ is not an exact value. It should be $0 < x < x_0$ and $x_0 < x < 2$ where $x_0 \approx 1.125$ is the unique real solution of $h(x) = 0$ on $(0, 2)$.  Also, rigorously, your statement "S-shape and hence there is at most one intersection" is the property of concave function, say $f(x) \ge \min(f(a), f(b))$ for a concave function $f(x)$ on $[a, b]$.

Comment: Although your whole proof with all details will be complicated, it is a proof. (+1).

Comment: I used your rigorous formulation "0<x<x0 and x0<x<2 where x0≈1.125 is the unique real solution of h(x)=0 on (0,2)" in the main text, thanks. W.r.t. the S-shape, there is s misconception on your side. The argument is as follows: as g(x) is a tangent line to a rising  function f(x) which is convex at the touching point x=1, we have f(x) > g(x) initially for x>1 as f(x) moves further up from g(x). Now, as we know that f(x) turns concave at x0≈1.125 > 1, f(x) will again turn towards g(x) for x > x0, which gives the S-shape. (continued)

Comment: (countinued) Generally, this concavity for x> x0 can result in 0 or 1 intersections of f(x) and g(x) at some x1> x0. Hence, if we find such an intersection x1 in the interval (x0,2), then f(x) > g(x) for (1,x1). This was used here, with $x1> \bar{x} = 1.429$. Since by calculation $f(\bar{x}) > g(\bar{x})$ ,  f(x) > g(x) definitely holds for  $x \in (1,\bar{x})$.

Comment: Your explanation is OK. Alternatively, we can say: Since $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ is concave on $[x_0, 2]$, and $f(x_0) \ge f(1) = 0$ and $f(1.429) \ge 0$, using the fact that $h(x) \ge \min(h(x_0), h(1.429)) $, we obtain $h(x) \ge 0$ on $[x_0, 1.429]$.

Comment: It seems someone downvoted you. It is not me.

Answer (score 2):

*Remark*: Here is a proof without calculus e.g. derivative and convexity (except for Bernoulli inequality).

**Proof**.

WLOG, assume that $a \ge b \ge c$. Clearly, $a \ge 1$ and $c \le 1$.

We split into five cases.

**Case 1**: $a \ge 2$

Using Bernoulli, we have
$$a^{4/a} \ge 1 + (a - 1)\cdot \frac4a
= 3 + \frac{2(a - 2)}{a} \ge 3.$$

**Case 2**: $8/5 \le a < 2$

Using Bernoulli, we have $a^{2/a} \ge 1 + (a - 1)\cdot \frac{2}{a} > 0$. Thus, we have
$$a^{4/a} = (a^{2/a})^2
\ge \left(1 + (a - 1)\cdot \frac2a\right)^2
= 3 + \frac{2(3a^2 - 6a + 2)}{a^2} \ge 3.$$

**Case 3**: $4/3 < a < 8/5$ and $c \le 1/2$

Using Bernoulli inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 a^{4/a} + b^{4/b} &\ge 1 + (a - 1)\cdot \frac4a + 1 + (b - 1)\cdot \frac4b\\[5pt]
 &= 10 - \frac4a - \frac4b\\[5pt]
 &= 10 - \frac4a - \frac{4}{3 - a - c}\\[5pt]
 &\ge 10 - \frac4a - \frac{4}{3 - a - 1/2}\\[5pt]
 &= 3 + \frac{35a - 14a^2 - 20}{a(5 - 2a)}\\
 &> 3.
\end{align*}

**Case 4**: $4/3 < a < 8/5$ and $c > 1/2$

Using Bernoulli, we have
$$a^{2/a} \ge 1 + (a - 1)\cdot \frac2a = 3 - \frac2a > 0, $$
and
$$b^{2/b} \ge 1 + (b - 1)\cdot \frac2b = 3 - \frac2b > 0$$
and
$$c^{1/c} \ge 1 + (c - 1)\cdot \frac1c = 2 - \frac1c > 0.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\left(3 - \frac2a\right)^2
+ \left(3 - \frac2b\right)^2
+ \left(2 - \frac1c\right)^4 \ge 3.$$

Let $p = a + b$ and $q = ab$. We have
\begin{align*}
 \left(3 - \frac2a\right)^2
 + \left(3 - \frac2b\right)^2
 &= 18 - \frac{12p - 8}{q} + \frac{4(p^2 - 4q)}{q^2}\\
 &\ge 18 - \frac{12p - 8}{q} + 4(p^2 - 4q)\left(\frac{2}{q} - 1\right)\\
 &= 16q + \frac{8p^2 - 12p + 8}{q} - 4p^2 - 14\\
 &\ge 2\sqrt{16q \cdot \frac{8p^2 - 12p + 8}{q}} - 4p^2 - 14 \\
 &= 16\sqrt{2p^2 - 3p + 2} - 4p^2 - 14
\end{align*}
where we have used $\frac{1}{q^2} \ge \frac{2}{q} - 1$ and AM-GM.

From $a > 4/3$, we have $c \le \frac{3 - 4/3}{2} = \frac56$.

It suffices to prove that, for all $c\in (1/2, 5/6]$,
$$16\sqrt{2(3-c)^2 - 3(3-c) + 2} - 4(3-c)^2 - 14 + \left(2 - \frac1c\right)^4 \ge 3$$
which is true.

**Case 5**: $a \le 4/3$

**Fact 1**: $x^{4/x} \ge 4x - 3$ on $(0, 4/3]$.
(The proof is given at the end.)

By Fact 1, we have
$$a^{4/a} + b^{4/b} + c^{4/c} \ge 4(a + b + c) - 9 = 3.$$

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

We only need to prove the case $x \in (3/4, 4/3]$.

Using Bernoulli, we have
$$x^{4/x} = (x^{\frac{4}{3x}})^3
\ge \Big(1 + (x - 1)\cdot \frac{4}{3x}\Big)^3
= 4x - 3 + \frac{4(52x - 27x^2 - 16)(x - 1)^2}{27x^3} \ge 4x - 3.$$

We are done.

Comment: Nice. But your original question (earlier text version) asked for sulutions with as few cases as possible. Now this is just what happened....

Comment: @ĐặngHảiĐăng About 3.3 due to arqady@AoPS in the link I gave in OP.

Comment: @Andreas However, now, the proof is more elementary, without using calculus (derivative, convexity, Lagrange Multiplier etc.). Actually, I think simple and elementary proofs are more important. For example, I hardly use Lagrange Multiplier for inequalities (particularly the contest inequalities). LM is something like "Break a butterfly on the wheel".

Comment: @Andreas In other words, if the proof is more elementary, even with more cases, it is fine. My original proof is complicated with more cases, it is not good.

Comment: @Andreas We split into several cases which are all proved using Bernoulli.  Actually, Case 1 and 2 can be combined if calculus is allowed i.e., the case $a \ge 8/5$. I pursue more elementary proofs which are kind to high school students, although my current proof is not nice.

Comment: @Andreas It is a pity there are always strange downvotes.

Comment: Although Andreas has a pretty nice solution, I still prefer this one, +1

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer just a remark :

Playing with Vasc's lemma 7.1 see (https://www.isr-publications.com/jnsa/articles-1563-proofs-of-three-open-inequalities-with-power-exponential-functions) we have the inequality for $1\leq x \leq 2$ and $a=x,c=\frac{2}{x}$ then :

$$\left((1-c)^{2}+ac(2-c)-ac(1-c)\ln a\right)^{2}\leq f(x)=x^{\frac{4}{x}}$$

I think it's pretty sharp to show the inequality even if now it seems a bit harder for the eyes .

On the other hand it seems that $f(x)$ is convex on $(0,1]$ so we can use the tangent line method .

I haven't yet an idea to find a lower bound on $(2,3)$.(No need in fact).

Edit we have using a simple bound on logarithm ($1\leq x \leq 2$,$a=x,c=\frac{2}{x}$):

$$\left((1-c)^{2}+ac(2-c)-ac(1-c)\cdot\frac{2\left(a-1\right)}{a+1}\right)^{2}\leq x^{\frac{4}{x}}$$

We can also use the RiverLi's bound or something else like for $x\in (0,1]$  :

$$x^{\frac{4}{x}}\geq g(x)=x^{5}\left(1+\left(\frac{4.25}{x}-5.25\right)\left(x-1\right)\right)$$

And obviously $0<x^{\frac{4}{x}}$.

It works as well .

We can also use Jensen's inequality because it's not hard to show that $g(x)$ is convex on $[1/3,1]$ and we have a polynomial inequality for $1\leq x \leq 2$:

$$2g\left(\frac{3-x}{2}\right)+f\left(x\right)\geq 3$$

We can also show that $f(x)$ is convex on $(0,9/8]$ remarking that :

$$2\cdot1.125^{\frac{4}{1.125}}>3$$

And use Jensen's inequality .

Remains to show the case $a\in(1,1.125),b\in(0,0.875),c\in(1.125,2)$ and for that use Jensen's inequality on the variable $a,b$ and we have with a such constraint :

$$2f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)+f\left(c\right)\geq 3$$

And use the bounds above .

We are done for this sketch of proof .

Comment: I think it at most provides partial answer.

Comment: @RiverLi $$x^{\frac{4}{x}}>4$$ for $x>2$ so If I go further (more details) It's complete ^^.

Comment: If you have a complete proof, give it with details.

Comment: @RiverLi I make some progress but I haven't yet a rigorous proof now .See you soon for that ^^.

Comment: @ĐặngHảiĐăng I think the current answer is not helpful. I hope he give a detailed proof (step-by-step).

Answer (score 0):

Using Vasc's paper and @Andreas have already shown that $f\left(x\right)=x^{\frac{4}{x}}$ is convex for $x\in(0,1]$ .So using WLCF-Theorem with an obvious statement we need to show for $1\leq x\leq 2$ :

$$\frac{1}{3}f\left(x\right)+\frac{2}{3}f\left(\frac{3-x}{2}\right)\geq 1$$

In my first answer I show :

*we have using a simple bound on logarithm* ($1\leq x \leq 2$,$a=x,c=\frac{2}{x}$):

$$g(x)=\left((1-c)^{2}+ac(2-c)-ac(1-c)\cdot\frac{2\left(a-1\right)}{a+1}\right)^{2}\leq x^{\frac{4}{x}}$$

So it's not hard to show for $1\leq x\leq 2$ :

$$\frac{1}{3}g\left(x\right)+\frac{2}{3}j\left(\frac{\left(3-x\right)}{2}\right)\geq 1$$

Where as in my first answer we have for $x\in(0,1]$:

$$j(x)=x^{5}\left(1+\left(\frac{4.25}{x}-5.25\right)\left(x-1\right)\right)\leq f(x)\tag{K}$$
In expanding and using factorization .

To show $(K)$ we have for $x\in[0.8,1]$:

By Bernoulli's inequality :

$$x^{-5+5+\frac{4}{x}}\geq x^{5}\left(1+\left(\frac{4}{x}-5\right)\left(x-1\right)\right)\geq x^{5}\left(1+\left(\frac{4.25}{x}-5.25\right)\left(x-1\right)\right)$$

For the other interval we can use derivative and a bound for logarithm knowing that $j(x)$ can be negative.

It completes this detailed sketch of proof .

Reference :

Cirtoaje, V., Baiesu, A. An extension of Jensen's discrete inequality to half convex functions. J Inequal Appl 2011, 101 (2011). https://doi.org/10.1186/1029-242X-2011-101

Comment: You need to give a complete detailed proof.

Comment: Also, you should not use the same symbols ($a, b, c$) in $a=x,c=\frac{2}{x}$ as in OP.

Answer (score -1):

I show the inequality (almost algebraically speaking) for $x\in[0,4/3]$ :

$$4\left(x-1\right)+1\leq x^{\frac{4}{x}}$$

In fact we have a stronger inequality for $x\in[3/4,4/3]$:

$$\left(x^{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(x-1\right)\right)\right)^{4}\leq x^{\frac{4}{x}}\tag{I}$$

To show it $(I)$ we use Bernoulli's inequality simply remarking :

$$x^{\frac{4}{x}}=\left(x^{\frac{1}{x}+0.25-0.25}\right)^4$$

Now see [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28x%5E%28-1%29%281%2B%28x%5E%28-4%29%2B1%2F4%29%28x%5E4-1%29%29%29%5E4-4%28x%5E4-1%29-1) for a factorization .

Except using derivative I cannot show this sixth degree polynomials is positive for $x\in[3/4,4/3]$

In fact we have clearly for $1\le x\le 4/3$:

$$x^{6}+30x^{5}-687x^{4}+400x^{3}+1632x^{2}-1280x+256>x^{4}+30x^{4}-687x^{4}+400x^{2}+1632x^{2}-1280x+256$$

We can use the second derivative or substitute by $y=x^2$ and factorize again a part.

For $3/4\le x\leq 1$ the sixth degree polynomials is increasing via derivative .